# Xcode - UIImageView stop at edge

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView being moved with a timer towards the edge of the view but it carries on and I don't know how to stop the UIImageView as soon as it hits he edge! Please Help?
This is what I have tried so far in my method!

Code:

```
-(void)moveBack {
CGPoint manCenter = man.center;
if (manCenter.x > 480) {
    manCenter.x = 480;
}

man.center = CGPointMake(man.center.x +5, man.center.y);
[self ifCollided];
}
```

Comment: You know the size of "man" right? Change ``480`` to ``480 - man.size.width / 2`` should work, given you know its center point.

Comment: I take time out of my schedule to help you out and answer your question. Someone copies my answer, then you unaccept my answer and accept the copied answer. Really lame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do your `man.center.x + 5` it will be out of the `UIImage` frame. When you set this to 480 it should be fitting.

```
-(void)moveBack {
    man.center = CGPointMake(man.center.x + 5, man.center.y);
    [self ifCollided];

    if (man.center.x > 480) {
        man.center = CGPointMake(480 , man.center.y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)moveBack {
    man.center = CGPointMake(man.center.x + 5, man.center.y);
    [self ifCollided];

    if (man.center.x > 480) {
        man.center = CGPointMake(480 , man.center.y);
    }
}
```